# How to interpret the noun phrase: "from employing" compared to "if it employed"

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

Do these sentences mean the same ?

I think the company would benefit **from employing** more persons.

I think the company would benefit **if it employed** more person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like the first sentence, but only because it's an overly complicated way to say something simple.  Otherwise, yes, both sentences mean the same thing.

In this case, I would use the verb "to hire" instead of "to employ":

> The company should hire more people.
>
> The company would benefit if it hired more people.

If you absolutely must, you can say, "The company would benefit from hiring more people".  But simple is better.

I prefer "to hire" because it focuses on the process of *increasing* the number of employees.  If instead you wanted to focus on the fact that there aren't currently enough employees, you would say something like:

> This company needs more employees.
>
> This company isn't effective because we don't have enough hands.
>
> We can't be effective until we increase our workforce.

Comment: At the same time "to employ" implies that the employees will actually be put to a purpose, vs. "to hire" which can just mean the process of adding them to the company.

Comment: @mstorkson Well, you're not hiring them to stand around and eat donuts, so the "purpose" part is implied.  But I agree which verb you use could be personal preference.